# Insert Assembly Attributes into AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to figure out how to use rosyln to insert assembly attributes into `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

My attributes look something like this:

```
[assembly: Foo(@"\\somepath\tosomething)"]
```

And I can read them like this:

```
var syntaxRoot = tree.GetRoot();

var attr = syntaxRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<AttributeSyntax>(); 
var attrNames = attr.Select(a => a.Name);
var deployments = attr.Where(a => a.Name.ToString() == "Foo")
    .Select(d => d.DescendantTokens()
    .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Kind() == SyntaxKind.StringLiteralToken).ValueText);
```

And I can get the argument that was passed to the attribute.

I can try to insert an attribute like so:

```
var list = new List<SyntaxNode>()
{
    SyntaxFactory.AttributeList(SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList<AttributeSyntax>(new List<AttributeSyntax>()
    {
        SyntaxFactory.Attribute(SyntaxFactory.ParseName("DeploymentLocation"))
    }))
};
var n = tree.GetRoot().InsertNodesAfter(tree.GetRoot().ChildNodes().Last(), list);
```

This will insert a node that ends up looking something like this:

```
...
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[DeploymentLocation]
```

So it's added my attribute, but it doesn't have the `assembly:` prefix and I can't figure out how to get the string literal arguments in there.

I know I could (and probably should) just load the file and use a simple text writer to insert strings, but in the interests of understanding how Roslyn is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

Pasting the code into [Roslyn Quoter](https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/) shows

```
    .WithTarget(
        AttributeTargetSpecifier(
            Token(SyntaxKind.AssemblyKeyword)))))
```